# add new editable item to listview when pull the list down

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

please i need to make the same effect of pull list down to add new empty item and edit it, and when list item lose focus it will be saved

please check the following android application to understand what i want to do

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuchdeid.clear&hl=en

if any one know any library of any algorithm that i can follow to make this behavior let me know.

Comment: In this some of functionality will possible and also some of you have to do with animation and some library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this one

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0352OH488M!

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pehim.png)

```
>XML Usage
```

If you decide to use SwipeListView as a view, you can define it in your xml layout like this:

```
<com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="[reveal | dismiss]"
        swipe:swipeActionRight="[reveal | dismiss]"
        swipe:swipeMode="[none | both | right | left]"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="[true | false]"
        swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="[true | false]"
        swipe:swipeAnimationTime="[miliseconds]"
        swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="[dimension]"
        swipe:swipeOffsetRight="[dimension]"
        />
```

1. swipeFrontView - Required - front view id.
2. swipeBackView - Required - back view id.
3. swipeActionLeft - Optional - left swipe action Default: 'reveal'
4. swipeActionRight - Optional - right swipe action Default: 'reveal'
5. swipeMode - Gestures to enable or 'none'. Default: 'both'
6. swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList - Close revealed items on list motion. Default: 'true'
7. swipeOpenOnLongPress - Reveal on long press Default: 'true'
8. swipeAnimationTime - item drop animation time. Default: android configuration
9. swipeOffsetLeft - left offset
10. swipeOffsetRight - right offset